# remove unnecessary files of library project

Tags: android, xml, apk

I am creating a application for android, in one of the activity i have used one library project for creating a panel which drops from top to bottom. Every thing is working fine and there are no errors. The reason for posting this question is that there are some unused images included in my .apk file which increases the size of application. I tried opening my apk file using winrar and then deleting the unused images and then again renaming its extension to .apk. but it didnt worked on my phone as there was the error stating `error parsing the XML file` when i tried to install the application. Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the un-used images from your project and export the .apk file again.
make sure you didn't delete images the you need.

Comment: the unused images are not in my project. they are in the library project and if i delete them, the library projects starts showing the error and even my app does not get compiled.

Comment: is that external jar (you are not the one who created it)? if yes it moght be ompossible for you to delete that images